# How can I create a custom data entry form for Excel?

Tags: excel, integration, export-to-excel, data-entry

I have very little experience in Excel, and I've spent ages trying to find an answer to this problem. I have a client who often creates proprietary Excel sheets for internal use in a very specific format.

So they have the data organized like A, B, C etc. in the sheet.

But they are copying over all that data from a source which organizes it B, C, A etc.

So in order to save them scrolling all over the place on both pages for hours, I need to create a data entry form which allows them to enter the data in the same order that the source organizes it (B, C, A etc.), but then enters the data into the correct places in the Excel sheet so that the output is organized like they want (A, B, C, etc.)

It seems like there should be a seriously simple answer, but it's killing me.

Comment: What is "the source" of the data?  Is somebody typing in a set of elements that make up a row in a table many times to fill in a table or is it just one set of values that you want to re-arrange on another sheet?

Comment: @Jeff H They’re copying select portions of data from a table on a website. If it helps, I can explain in more exhaustive detail.